# How do use plt.scatter() to visualize a centered dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

having a given random dataset, which we will call X

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = # a dataset
```

How do I center the data and plot this?
I know I should use

```
 np.mean(X, #something)
```

to center the data.
But how do I plot/ visualize this using plt.scatter() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply subtract a mean of each variable from every value. For 2 dimensional case:

```py
plt.scatter(X[:, 0] - X[:, 0].mean(), X[:, 1] - X[:, 1].mean(), s=75)
plt.scatter(0, 0, c='r', s=75)  # mean is now 0, 0
plt.xlim((-0.75, 0.75))
plt.ylim((-0.75, 0.75))
```

[image: img]